# Converting label to a checkboxlist

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, label, checkboxlist

Note: I'm new to asp and sql. Trying to fix some old code that isn't mine.

I have a page that contains a DropDownList with some user names from a database. Upon clicking one of those user names, a list appears above the DropDownList of dates pulled from the database based on the user. Right now, that "list" of dates is a label and the .text of that label is being changed. I would like to instead make each of those dates associated with a checkbox that I can then manipulate later based on whether it is checked or not.

.aspx page:

```
<anthem:Label ID="OpenTime" runat="server" />
```

.cs page:

```
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = gConn;

        if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Approver") == true)
        {
            DropDownList ddlActingAs = (DropDownList)LoginView1.FindControl("ddlActingAs");
            OpenTime.Text = "";
            String sql = "SELECT StartDate FROM Periods WHERE User_ID = @userid AND (PeriodStatus_ID = 1 OR PeriodStatus_ID = 2) ORDER BY StartDate DESC";
            command.CommandText = sql;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("userid", ddlActingAs.SelectedValue.ToString()));
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
                OpenTime.Text += "<br>" + reader.GetDateTime(0).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " is open";
            OpenTime.UpdateAfterCallBack = true;
            reader.Close();
        }
```

Example:

[image]

For starters, I replaced the label with a checkboxlist like so:

```
<anthem:CheckBoxList ID="CheckTest" runat="server" />
```

Then I essentially tried replacing all "OpenTime" with "CheckTest". I messed around with the .DataSource and .Databind methods of a checkboxlist but with no luck.

Not sure what the right way to go about this is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first you need to store your dates into a list to be able to bind it later into a **Grid** or a **Repeater**. Since you need a **CheckBoxList** you may use a **TemplateField**.

Add the dates to the list from the database.

```
IList<DateTime> dateList = new List<DateTime>();
 while (reader.Read())
 {
   //Check if your reader is not empty and has a valid date before adding.
   dateList.add(reader.GetDateTime(0).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
 }
```

**EDIT**

**Suppose you have this class**

```
 public class MyCustomDate
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

**In your page load the code would be something similar to this**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            IList<MyCustomDate> dates = new List<MyCustomDate>();

            dates.Add(new MyCustomDate() { Date = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1), IsChecked = true, Description = "First Date" });
            dates.Add(new MyCustomDate() { Date = DateTime.Now.AddYears(2), IsChecked = false, Description = "Second Date" });
            dates.Add(new MyCustomDate() { Date = DateTime.Now.AddYears(3), IsChecked = true, Description = "Third Date" });


            this.rptTest.DataSource = dates;
            this.rptTest.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

**Your HTML would be**

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptTest" >
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table style="width: 100%">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span><%# Eval("Description") %></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkTest" runat="server" Checked='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsChecked"))%>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Once you have that you can bind the list into a repeater or grid with template field. [Repeater Example Link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1328736.aspx?checkboxlist%20in%20repeater)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I tried a repeater but with no luck. Could you post an example that's a little clearer than what's on that link?

Comment: I actually got it working! Decided to go with a ListItem instead and add those to the checkboxlist.items but I have some things I want to use repeaters for in the future so thank you suggestion.

Comment: Oh I just updated it! lol. Good luck man. Hope this update would make things easier to you.